# Searching through an array, and outputting the element number

Tags: java, arrays, search

I am writing a program that allows a user to input any of the items listed in the array, and will output the element number of that item.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] menu = {"apples", "bananas", "pears", "milk", "cookies", "bread", "lemons"};

    Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String item;
    item = user_input.next();
```

How I can do this?

Comment: How would you explain it to a robot? What would be the next step now that you have an Array of stuff and one other "stuff" to find in that array.

Comment: I know for sure that i have to make a for loop and have i as the counter just like Forseth said, and ive tried exactly what he showed beforehand and it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < menu.length; i++){
  if(menu[i].equalsIgnoreCase(item)){
    //Do what you want with i as the index.
    break;
  }
}
```

This loops through the array to find the one which matches what has been searched.

Comment: How is this incorrect? Edit: Never mind. I just realized I was comparing the strings wrong.

Comment: Both your solutions were incorrect. Ive tried the first one, and it ends the program. This .equalsIgnoreCase(item) doesn't work either, it simply outputs the item itself and not the element number

Comment: Nevermind, the equalsIgnoreCase works. Ive never seen that command before. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Lets's try this one :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Stack {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String[] menu = {"apples", "bananas", "pears", "milk", "cookies", "bread", "lemons"};

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enater a value to search : ");

        String user_input  = keyboard.next();

        boolean found=false;
        int location = 0;

        for(int i=0;i<menu.length;i++)
        {
            if(menu[i].equalsIgnoreCase(user_input))
            {
                found=true;
                location = i;
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
        if(found)
        {
            System.out.println("String found at location : " +location);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("String not found!");
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
   import java.util.Scanner;

   public class MenuCard {

   public static void main(String[] args) {



        String[] menu = {"apples","apples", "bananas", "pears", "milk", "cookies", "bread", "lemons"};

        int count=0;

        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(" type any item to check in menu");
        String item;
        item = user_input.next();
        for(String s:menu)
        {
              if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(item))
              {
                  count++;

              }

        }
        System.out.println("no. of item is "+count);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not using library methods?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MenuCard {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] menu = { "apples", "apples", "bananas", "pears", "milk",
                "cookies", "bread", "lemons" };

        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(" type any item to check in menu");
        String item;
        item = user_input.next();
        int count = Arrays.asList(menu).indexOf(item.toLowerCase());
        if(count < 0)
            System.out.println("Item not found");
        else
            System.out.println("no. of item is " + count);
    }
}
```

First you convert your array to `List` via [`Arrays.asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29), then you use [`List.indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29) method. To find index of the list element.